# SQL Query to select duplicate registrations

Tags: sql, duplicates

Hi sorry for what seems such a simple question in advance...

I have a table with some millions of rows of laboratory data and the following fields (amongst others)

- Laboratory Reference Number
- Forename
- Surname
- DOB

I need to do a query that will give me all of the distinct laboratory Reference Number
, forename, surname and DOBs where the laboratory Reference Number
has more than one associated forename, surname and DOB.

i.e. a query to highlight where a laboratory Reference Number has duplicate candidates associated with it

e.g.

```
12345, Bob, Smith, 30/038/1981
12345, Fred, Smith, 31/03/1981
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: post your full database schema please

Comment: What DBMS? Did you try anything? If yes, please post it and the problems. If not: Why not?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: Not really necessary. The question contains the relevant information.

Comment: No. As I can see, `30/038/1981` is a DOB from alien planet, and we do not know the column names.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: The 038 is a typo and the column names are there. Hint 1: look at the bullet points. Hint 2: Column names can contain spaces.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE REF IN
  (SELECT REF FROM TABLE GROUP BY REF HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

You could also use `SELECT DISTINCT *` if necessary

Comment: +1 This would return two identical rows, even though the REF would be associated with the same `FirstName, Surname, Dob`.  I guess that's what the OP is after though :)

Comment: Yes - I edited my answer a moment or two later because it wasn't 100% clear what the OP wanted

Answer (score 1):

```
select  RefNr
,       Forename
,       Surname
,       DOB
from    YourTable yt1
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt1.RefNr = yt2.RefNr
                and 
                (
                    yt1.Forename <> yt2.Forename
                    or yt1.Surname <> yt2.Surname
                    or yt1.DOB <> yt2.DOB
                )
        )
```

Comment: This is a good answer - it depends on how you read the question - if Bob Smith Appears twice (Same DoB) is that a duplicate ? If not then this is a better answer than mine below